# How to resolve the error 'No space left on device' in Google Cloud Shell? Is there any specific cloud shell command to run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quotas-limits#disk_storage):

> Cloud Shell provisions 5 GB of free persistent disk storage mounted as your $HOME directory on the virtual machine instance. This storage is on a per-user basis and is available across projects. All files you store in your home directory, including installed software, scripts, and user configuration files like .bashrc and .vimrc, persist between sessions and count towards the 5 GB limit.

I understand that I ran out of disk space but the docs didn't mention how to free up space in home directory. Is there any cloud shell command to run for me to free up some space? Still a novice in GCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several Linux commands that you can use.

- **ls -la** List the files in the current directory
- **ls -la DIRECTORY** List the files in the specified directory
- **find DIRECTORY -type file -exec ls -la {} \;** list all the files in the specified directory and subdirectores. This will display hidden files.
- **rm FILENAME** delete a file

There are many more. Those commands will help you list files and determine which ones you can delete.

You can combine commands to help you determine how space is used. For example, to list the 20 largest files starting at the current directory:

```
du -a . | sort -n -r | head -n 20
```